# Codeigniter : retrieve lastest row in table?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
table name : mytable 
   id name salt value
    1   a    10   39   
    2   a    20   13   
    3   a    10   14   
    4   b    40   39
```

mymodel.php

```
 function get_value_by_name($name)
    {
     $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("mytable");
        $this->db->where('salt', '10');
        $this->db->where('name', $name);
        $this->db->order_by('id',"ASC");

        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query=$this->db->get();
            if($query != null){
                return $query->result();
                }
        else{
                    return array();
                }

    }
```

I want to get latest row with name= a and salt=10 (row with id = 3). But my current code return 1st row.

Comment: You know the opposite of ascending? Take the first four characters of it and use that in the order by

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   $this->db->order_by('id',"ASC");
```

By

```
   $this->db->order_by('id',"DESC");
```